# Can I get the response server name/ip using Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache-commons, big-ip

I'm using Apache HttpClient 3.x for contacting a Big IP that will then redirect my request to one of 1-N machines.  We have the need to know which of the N machines actually picked up the request though, and I'm not sure how to get this information.  I looked through the Response headers with no luck, so I'm wondering if this information is actually provided anywhere?  Is there a helper/utility class I can use to get any additional metadata?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you in control of the 1-N servers that is processing your request?

Comment: Not our group personally, but it's all internal so we could request them to add something to the response.  I guess I was looking if there was some way to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I think response headers are going to be your only option AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request is redirected and you need the new location, you need to `setFollowRedirects(false)` on the method and handle the redirect yourself.

After sending the request, check `getStatusCode()` for `302` and `getResponseHeader("Location")` for the new address. Than change the address by `setURI()` and send again.

Comment: Wow, that would probably work.  Not sure if I want to inherit that redirecting responsibility but unless someone else can come up with something better, I'll mark this as an answer in a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html) and insert a unique Header ID on each one of your Apache httpd servers ;-)